# Как адаптировать код под поиск устройств в сети?

Tags: c++, winapi, сеть

Есть код, который почти полностью был скопирован из [статьи MSDN:](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/WNet/enumerating-network-resources)

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumResources(LPNETRESOURCE lpNR = nullptr){
    HANDLE hNetEnum;
    DWORD dwResultOpen = WNetOpenEnum(RESOURCE_CONTEXT,
                                      NULL,
                                      0,
                                      lpNR,
                                      &hNetEnum);

    if(dwResultOpen != NO_ERROR)
        return FALSE;

    constexpr DWORD numOfResources = 2048;
    DWORD count = -1;
    DWORD cbBuffer = numOfResources * sizeof (NETRESOURCE);
    DWORD dwResultEnum = 0;
    LPNETRESOURCE lpNRlocal = new NETRESOURCE[numOfResources];

    do{
        dwResultEnum = WNetEnumResource(hNetEnum, &count, lpNRlocal, &cbBuffer);
        if(dwResultEnum == NO_ERROR){
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
                cout << "Resource found!: " << lpNRlocal[i].lpLocalName << endl;
                if(RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER == (lpNRlocal[i].dwUsage & RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER))
                    if(!EnumResources(&lpNRlocal[i]))
                        cout << "error enum resources\n";
            }
        }

    }while(dwResultEnum != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS);

    delete [] lpNRlocal;
    CloseHandle(hNetEnum);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Проблема в том, что этот код выполняется долго, а как выполняется - дает просто список контейнеров (хотя надеялся больше типов будет). Подскажите пожалуйста, у кого был опыт работы с данными функциями - как адаптировать код выше, чтобы он выводил ip адреса устройств в локальной сети?

Comment: А код выше не должен выводить ip адреса устройств в локальной сети.

Answer (score 1):

С данным кодом есть несколько проблем:

- Если вас интересуют компьютеры, а не общие каталоги, вам и не надо раскрывать контейнеры, достаточно перечислить элементы на основном уровне вложенности.
- Для компьютеров в качестве имени нужно брать не lpLocalName, а lpRemoteName; локальное имя для них все равно будет NULL.
- Закрывать дескриптор надо WNetCloseEnum, а не CloseHandle

Ну, а чтобы получить IP-адреса, необходимо добавить разрешение имен. Если исправить ошибки в вашем коде и добавить его, получится такой код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "Mpr.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

std::wstring ResolveAddr(WCHAR* addr) {

    ADDRINFOW *result = NULL;   
    ADDRINFOW hints;
    LPSOCKADDR sockaddr_ip;
    wchar_t ipstringbuffer[46];
    DWORD ipbufferlength;
    DWORD res;  
    int iRetval;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;       

    res = GetAddrInfoW(addr, nullptr, &hints, &result);
    if (res != 0) {
        wprintf(L"GetAddrInfoW failed with error: %d\n", res);
        return std::wstring(L"");
    }

    if (result->ai_family != AF_INET) {
        wprintf(L"Error: Unsupported address\n", res);
        return std::wstring(L"");
    }

    sockaddr_ip = result->ai_addr;
    ipbufferlength = 46;
    iRetval = WSAAddressToString(sockaddr_ip, (DWORD)result->ai_addrlen, NULL,
        ipstringbuffer, &ipbufferlength);

    if (iRetval) {
        wprintf(L"WSAAddressToString failed with %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return std::wstring(L"");
    }

    return std::wstring(ipstringbuffer);    
}

BOOL WINAPI EnumResources(LPNETRESOURCE lpNR = nullptr) {

    HANDLE hNetEnum;
    DWORD dwResultOpen = WNetOpenEnumW(RESOURCE_CONTEXT,
        NULL,
        0,
        lpNR,
        &hNetEnum);

    if (dwResultOpen != NO_ERROR)
        return FALSE;

    constexpr DWORD numOfResources = 2048;
    DWORD count = -1;
    DWORD cbBuffer = numOfResources * sizeof(NETRESOURCE);
    DWORD dwResultEnum = 0;
    LPNETRESOURCE lpNRlocal = new NETRESOURCE[numOfResources]; 
    WCHAR* pwc;

    do {
        dwResultEnum = WNetEnumResourceW(hNetEnum, &count, lpNRlocal, &cbBuffer);

        if (dwResultEnum == NO_ERROR) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

                if (lpNRlocal[i].lpRemoteName == nullptr) continue;

                std::wcout << lpNRlocal[i].lpRemoteName << L": ";
                pwc = lpNRlocal[i].lpRemoteName;
                if (wcslen(pwc) > 2) {
                    if(pwc[0]=='\\' && pwc[1]=='\\') pwc = lpNRlocal[i].lpRemoteName + 2;
                }               

                std::wcout << ResolveAddr(pwc).c_str() << std::endl;        
            }           
        }       
        else if (dwResultEnum != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) {
            std::wcout << L"WNetEnumResourceW error: "<< dwResultEnum << std::endl;
        }

    } while (dwResultEnum != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS);

    delete[] lpNRlocal;
    WNetCloseEnum(hNetEnum);

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }   

    EnumResources();

    getchar();
}
```

Так как данный код завязан на сетевое обнаружение (которое использует в том числе широковещательные запросы протоколов NetBIOS/WS-Discovery/UPnP/SSDP в зависимости от версии и конфигурации Windows), насколько быстро он будет работать, и будет ли работать вообще, зависит от многих факторов. Если вы хотите более надежный способ получения списка компьютеров для доменных сетей, смотрите в сторону [ADSI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ADSI/active-directory-service-interfaces-adsi).